# Accept parameters from a .Net console app into a Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to pass parameters from a .Net console app to a batch file. The parameters are not coming into the batch file.

**How can I properly set up passing the parameters into the bat file?**

Here is the method in the console app that I'm executing.

```
private static int ProcessBatFile(string ifldr, string ofldr, string iext, string oext, Int16 filewidth, Int16 fileheight, Int16 ctr)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("BatProcessDir") + "imagemagick.bat";
            psi.Arguments = "-ifldr=" + ifldr + " -ofldr=" + ofldr + " -iext=" + iext + " -oext=" + oext + " -iwid=" + filewidth + " -ihgt=" + fileheight;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            process.Start();

            return ctr;
        }
```

Below, is the code in the bat file I'm trying to execute:

```
@echo on

echo %ofldr%

echo %ifldr%

echo %iwid%

echo %ihgt% 

echo %oext% 

echo %iext%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass them as paramters, you can do this in the c# code:

```
psi.Arguments = ifldr + " " + ofldr + " " + iext + " " + oext + " " + filewidth + " " + fileheight;
```

and do this in the batch file:

```
@echo on
set ifldr=%1
set ofldr=%2
set iext=%3
set oext=%4
set iwid=%5
set ihgt=%6

echo %ofldr%
echo %ifldr%
echo %iwid%
echo %ihgt% 
echo %oext% 
echo %iext%
```

As an alternative solution, you can also directly modify the environment before executing the batch file using `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("ifldr", ifldr);
....
```

This causes less problems if the parameters may contain spaces.